# multiple calls to web service with flex/AMF?

Tags: flex4, amf

I'm using flex & AMF to make a web service call.
When the application loads I'm calling to 4 operations from the same service.
as far as I know flex should start to render the UI once it gets the result.
But in my case I can see in the fiddler that all the calls to the operations are using the same HTTP request. This means that the flex is waiting to the response from all operations.
I was wondering if there is something I can do to split the calls ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. Do the next service call in your result method of your responder.